# Ring-isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2 - 1) \cong R $

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> I've checked that $R = \{(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}: a\equiv b \pmod 2\}$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$. I want to show that $$\mathbb{Z}[X] /(X^2-1) \cong R,$$ where $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is the polynomial ring with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$.

I haven't found a function for which $f\colon \mathbb{Z}[X]\to R$ is surjective, and I think it will be difficult for me to show that $\ker(f) \subset (X^2 - 1)$ since this was the case in other comparable proofs I've tried. Can you help me with this / give me some more direction?

Comment: How about $f(X)\mapsto(f(1),f(-1))$?

Comment: Thanks, this helps. Can you also tell me how to show that $\forall$  p(X) $ \in $ ker(f) | p(X) $\in \mathbb{Z}[X](X^2 - 1) $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Since $f(x)-f(y)\;$is divisible by $x-y\;$in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$, it follows that $(m-n)\mid (f(m) - f(n))$ for all integers $m,n$.

In particular, using $m=1,\;n=-1$, we get $f(1) \equiv f(-1)\;(\text{mod}\;2)$.

Let $I$ denote the ideal $(x^2-1)$ of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Let $R\;$be the subring of $\mathbb{Z}{\,\times\,}\mathbb{Z}$ defined by
$$R = \{(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}{\,\times\,}\mathbb{Z} \mid a \equiv b\;(\text{mod}\;2)\}$$
and let $\phi:\mathbb{Z}[x] \to R\;$be defined by
$$\phi(f) = (f(1),f(-1))$$

It's routine to verify that $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism.

Moreover, $\phi$ is surjective, since, if $(a,b) \in R$, then
$$\phi(cx + d) = (a,b)$$
where $c,d$ are defined by
$$c=\frac{a-b}{2},\;\;d=\frac{a+b}{2}$$

Computing the kernel of $\phi$,
\begin{align*}
&\phi(f) = (0,0)\\[4pt]
\iff\;&(f(1),f(-1))=(0,0)\\[4pt]
\iff\;&f(1) = 0\;\,\text{and}\;\,f(-1)=0\\[4pt]
\iff\;&(x-1){\mid}f\;\,\text{and}\;\,(x+1){\mid}f\\[4pt]
\iff\;&(x^2-1){\mid}f\\[4pt]
\iff\;&f \in I\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
so the kernel of $\phi$ is $I$.

It follows thar $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I \cong R$, as was to be shown.