# Is $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ isomorphic to the ring of symmetric integer matrices with same diagonal elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R= \left\{
\begin{bmatrix}
  a & b \\
  b & a \\
\end{bmatrix} : a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \right\} $ be the ring of symmetric integer matrices with same diagonal elements.

Is the ring $R$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ ?

My thoughts:

The two rings are very similar. They have the same amount of inversible elements, $U(R)= \left\{
\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix}
  -1 & 0 \\
  0 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix},  \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & -1 \\
  -1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} \right\} $ and $U(\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}) = \{(1,1),(-1,-1),(1,-1),(-1,1)\}$.

I have tried $f:R \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z},
f\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
  a & b \\
  b & a \\
\end{bmatrix}\right)=(a,b) $, which fails to be homorphism, due to multiplication.

I have also tried $g:R \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z},
g\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
  a & b \\
  b & a \\
\end{bmatrix}\right)=(a-b,a+b) $, which fails to be a surjection, even though it is injective homomorphism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ring $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ has two nonzero orthogonal idempotents (elements $e=(1,0)$, $f=(0,1)$ which satisfy $e^2=e$, $f^2=f$, and $ef=(0,0)=fe$). But the ring of symmetric $2\times2$ integer matrices only has one nonzero idempotent, the identity$I_2$. (Check this by writing $A^2=A$ and solving $b=0$, $a=-1$.) So the rings cannot be isomorphic. But your $(a+b,a-b)$ map shows the matrix ring is isomorphic to the subring of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ of pairs of integers with the same parity.

Answer (score 4):

You can write every element in $R$ as $aI+bJ$ with
$$
I=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \cr 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},\;
J=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \cr 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
We have $I^2=I, J^2=I$ and $IJ=JI=J$. The ring is isomorphic to
$$
R\cong \Bbb Z[X]/(X^2-1) 
$$
Indeed, we can define a unique homomorphism
$$
f\colon\mathbb{Z}[X]\to R
$$
by $f(X)=J$. Then $f$ is surjective and its kernel is the ideal generated by $X^2-1$.

Note that this ring is not isomorphic to $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$, see here:

[$\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2-1)$ is not isomorphic with $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454493/mathbbzx-x2-1-is-not-isomorphic-with-mathbbz-times-mathbbz)

See also the following post

[Ring-isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2 - 1) \cong R $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2452690/ring-isomorphism-mathbbzx-x2-1-cong-r)